# google chart with multiple dates

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have multiple collections of data I want to display in a single google chart. Each series is a collection of CPM's with a date:

for instance:

```
series A[
  '2016-09-01' => 2.08023,
  '2016-09-04' => 2.01123
];

series B[
  '2016-09-01' => 1.99324,
  '2016-09-02' => 2.00112
];
```

Note that the dates in the two series are not the same. I want to draw these two graphs in a single google graph. How should I format the data rows (if this is possible at all).

I have made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gcp40c0o/1/) with what I thought would be a way to go, but adding a null in the data table doesn't work, I get two dots for the first series where I'm expecting a line. How can I make google chart draw the line instead of the dots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the fiddle, the data is setup correctly

however, since there is a `null` value is *Series A* due to the different dates

need to use [configuration option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options) `interpolateNulls: true`

from the documentation...

> **interpolateNulls**
>   Whether to guess the value of missing points. If true, it will guess the value of any missing data based on neighboring points. If false, it will leave a break in the line at the unknown point.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'series a');
  data.addColumn('number', 'series b')
  data.addRows([
    [new Date( 1472688000000 ), 2.08023, 1.99324],
    [new Date( 1472774400000 ), null,    2.00112],
    [new Date( 1472947200000 ), 2.01123, null]
  ]);

  var options = {
    interpolateNulls: true
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```